# Kendo UI: grid and panelbar

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-panelbar

I want to implement the following:

[image]

so, Kendo UI Grid and inside each row it has a panelbar. I try to find a solution, but most cases are vice versa: add a grid to panelbar. 
As I understand, I just need to add a child row to every row of grid. How to implement it?

I use ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Did you try with `Detail Template`?  https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/detailtemplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the `Detail Template of Grid`.

Here is the sample : [Dojo Sample](http://runner.telerik.io/fullscreen/UCUMEDoR/2)

Check the **reference** here : [Detail template](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/detailtemplate)